# Compute betweenness centrality on a (1M,3M)-graph using graph-tool

Tags: performance, graph, graph-tool

I am trying to compute betweenness centrality on a 1M nodes 3M edges graph. **I am using graph-tool** and the following lines of code:

```
from graph_tool.all import *
g = load_graph("youtube.graphml")
scores = graph_tool.centrality.betweenness(g)
```

In its performance comparisons page, it is reported that to compute betweenness on a (40k, 300k)-directed_graph, graph-tool takes about **4 minutes**. https://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance

Since graph-tool uses Brandes algorithm, which has a O(VE) complexity, I was expecting an approximated running time of:

```
(1M/40k)*(3M/300k)*4m=25*10*4m=1000m~17h
```

I found this calculation coherent with the following [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465503/networkx-never-finishes-calculating-betweenness-centrality-for-2-mil-nodes) post, where for a (2M,5M)-graph an user gave an approximated running time of 6 months using NetworkX,which is x180 slower than graph-tool. Hence:

```
6 months = 180 days(NetworkX) ~ 1 day(graph-tool)
```

The point is that my program is running on a 4-core machine since 2 days, so I am starting to wonder if my reasoning makes any sense.

Moreover graph-tools benchmarks are performed on a directed graph, for which Brandes algorithm has a complexity of `O(VE+V(V+E)logV)`. Given this point, shouldn't be the expected running time even smaller than previously written? And more importantly **Is it feasible at all to compute betweenness centrality on a (1M,3M)-network using graph-tool and a 4-core machine?**

I am using an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Eventually the algorithm **stopped**:

  - It took slightly more than **2
    days** (a couple of hours more).
- I was **not able to get the result**:

  - During the computation the
    UI crashed and I was not able to reconnect to the ipython notebook
    kernel which was running the program (which however kept running).
- I am going to update this post as soon as I get the actual result.

**UPDATE**
I recomputed the betweenness using a 16 core machine and it took about **18 hours**.