# Centrality using networkx-python in short time

Tags: python, graph, networkx, approximation

Is there any way to calculate the centrality measures(closeness, betweenness) in short time approximately.
I've tried the inbuilt functions( nx.closeness_centrality(), nx.betweenness_centrality(F)), but it is taking forever to compute for a Directed graph with some 10k nodes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465503/networkx-never-finishes-calculating-betweenness-centrality-for-2-mil-nodes/32468942#32468942

Comment: For a full answer, it would help to see what you have right now.