# Betweeness Centrality and closeness centrality execution time

Tags: python, graph, networkx

How to reduce execution time of Betweeness Centrality and closeness centrality using networkx for a graph with 331957 edges and 298002.

Thanks

Comment: You're actually asking 2 questions here.  For Betweenness centrality, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32465503/2966723.  Not sure about closeness centrality

Comment: Thanks but still didn't find a solution to closeness centrality